# В чем основные отличия GC в .NET 4.6 от 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

В чем основные отличия GC в .NET 4.6 (4.6.2) от 4.5? Как могут эти отличия, в теории, сказаться на производительности приложения?

Comment: здесь - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx
но я сильно сомневаюсь, что в Вашем случае это сильно скажется на производительности.

Answer (score 4):

Согласно [пресс-релизу](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx#v46), появилось несколько изменений:

- Класс `GC` теперь включает методы [`TryStartNoGCRegion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906201(v=vs.110).aspx) и
  [`EndNoGCRegion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.endnogcregion(v=vs.110).aspx), которые позволяют *попробовать* запретить сборку мусора в определенном участке кода/пути исполнения. Это может пригодиться, если участок кода **очень** критичный и важно не прерываться на GC-паузы.
- Появилась новая перегрузка метода
  [`GC.Collect(Int32, GCCollectionMode, Boolean, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906200(v=vs.110).aspx), которая
  позволяет контролировать режим сборки мусора для small object heap и
  large object heap: только сборка или сборка плюс сжатие. Первый режим
  будет работать быстрее, второй позволит уменьшить memory footprint.
- Появилась возможность выполнять сжатие large object heap во время
  сборки мусора, см. в свойство
  [`GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx). Это позволит уменьшить memory footprint ценой чуть более долгой сборки мусора. (Но, как говорится, если у вас растет LOH, то вы лох.) Нужно помнить, что это свойство "однократное" -- оно указывает, что при *следующей полной* сборке мусора GC следует также сжать LOH.

Об изменениях внутренних алгоритмов и эвристик, улучшении производительности сборщика ничего не известно. Все описанные выше изменения -- из разряда более тонкой настройки и нужны, думаю, лишь 0.001% приложений.